# Curl. Ошибка 302. followlocation не помогает

Tags: php, curl

Привет всем. Пытаюсь получить контент страницы "http://www.baiterek.gov.kz/ru". Получаю `302 - "The document has moved here"`. followlocation изначально стоял true.
Моя функция:

```
function get_web_page($url)
{
    $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";  
    $ch = curl_init( $url );   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"d://coo.txt");    
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );     
    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

Comment: У меня не воспроизвелось, все отработало как надо. PHP 7.0

Comment: @ilyaplot, в чем может быть проблема? может это как-то связано с сервером?

Comment: Возможно, но я не уверен, что используется именно приведенный в вопросе код.

Comment: Полная ситуация такая:

Comment: Я парсил этот сайт с одного сервера. Потом их админ заблочил мой IP. тогда я разместил парсер на другой сервер. Там я получил необходимый контент. В итоге теперь я паршу мой второй сервер, который принимает параметр url, и выводит контент этой странице. И вот на первом сервере я и получаю 302

Comment: А код из вопроса с какого сервера? С первого или со второго? Вообще для таких случаев используется прокси или VPN, если прокси нет.